# RestTemplate - POST request for "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token" resulted in 406 (Not Acceptable); invoking error handler

Tags: spring, code-signing, spring-social

since morning I'm struggling out to understund how to implement a SignIn capability between my webApp (Spring-MVC) and Spring-Social.
I'm using XML configuration and it seems working good. I got troubles signIn using for exemple twitter. I show you my stack-trace prints out:

```
InvocableHandlerMethod - Invoking [signIn] method with arguments [twitter, ServletWebRequest: uri=/SitiPreventivi/signin/twitter;client=127.0.0.1;session=6EE8AE04F40C32C823646844BF36378B]
2013-01-12 18:21:16,168 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] HttpAccessor - Created POST request for "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
2013-01-12 18:21:16,169 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] RestTemplate$AcceptHeaderRequestCallback - Setting request Accept header to [application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data]
2013-01-12 18:21:17,317 WARN [http-bio-8080-exec-7] RestTemplate - POST request for "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token" resulted in 406 (Not Acceptable); invoking error handler
2013-01-12 18:21:17,326 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] InvocableHandlerMethod - Method [signIn] returned [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView: unnamed; URL [/signin?error=provider]]
2013-01-12 18:21:17,326 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView: unnamed; URL [/signin?error=provider]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SitiPreventivi Servlet'
2013-01-12 18:21:17,326 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] AbstractView - Rendering view with name 'null' with model {} and static attributes {}
```

I show you just the relevant part about my problem.
As you can see the post request to the correct url is made, but I get a 406 error which I cannot explain.
Is there a way to work the problem out?

Thanks in advance.

Claudio

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem by setting the callback URL on Twitter application settings.

You can find more details [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?119888-twitter-406-error):

It’s worth noting that twitter doesn’t accept callback URL to be localhost:8080… So, in case you want the callback URL to be localhost, you can edit the Host file on your computer and add the localhost name resolution. E.g.:

127.0.0.1       local.your-domain.com

Then, you can set the callback URL to `http://local.your-domain.com:8080/`